# Sidebar next page error in FortySecondsCV LaTeX template

Tags: page-breaking, cv

I'm using a template from [forty-seconds-cv template](https://fr.overleaf.com/latex/templates/forty-seconds-cv/pztcktmyngsk)

I have a problem when adding more sections in sidebar in the 2nd page, the sections do not go to the next page. Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Developer here.
Do I understand correctly: You filled the sidebar on 2nd page already (presumably via `\addtobacksidebar`), added even more sections there and expected them to be visible on a 3rd page?

If that's the case, then the solution is to manually create a 3rd (or in general n-th) page and add a new sidebar environment, which can then be filled as usual:

```latex
\newpage

\begin{sidebar}
  \sidesection{Another Sidebar Section}
  % sidebar content of 3rd page here
\end{sidebar}

\cvsection{Another Body Section}
% body content of 3rd page here
```

Letting a sidebar overflow will not automagically lead to new pages as would be the case for regular prose text in the body of a simple LaTeX document. You can think of sidebars as "boxes" of page height and some pre-defined width which are restricted to the page where they have been "created" (using the [textpos](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) package). You can find more information on specific layout elements in the [official documentation](https://github.com/PandaScience/FortySecondsCV#sidebar).

Note: Posting your question directly in the corresponding [GitHub repository](https://github.com/PandaScience/FortySecondsCV) as an issue will raise the chances of a prompt answer. ;-)